# How to get "Forms" folder in a document library

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I want to get properties of the "Forms" folder in a document library, but getting 404 NotFound.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!PQz7QSyZm0-bePWjkO6mFndUpviN2NFGq-vEw0NG40IxzH03FdAMSbRgePxu7s5Z/items/01BL4KB4V6Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ:/Forms

404 NotFound
{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "The resource could not be found.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-05-29T08:25:45",
            "request-id": "2cef83cf-70f6-46dd-aa2e-390f6b58370c",
            "client-request-id": "365f9753-726c-e908-8844-b9acca7778a9"
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I try to create a "Forms" folder, I will get 400 BadRequest

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!PQz7QSyZm0-bePWjkO6mFndUpviN2NFGq-vEw0NG40IxzH03FdAMSbRgePxu7s5Z/items/01BL4KB4V6Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ/children

{
    "name": "Forms",
    "folder": {}
}

400 BadRequest
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Name is reserved for list forms folder.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-05-29T08:27:37",
            "request-id": "5756c48e-1d9f-4bdd-8a02-f598cd69d257",
            "client-request-id": "1234c89f-58b2-60b3-7fe8-f1c5ec2eaefd"
        }
    }
}
```

How could I get the "Forms" folder?

--

The webURL of the document library is

```
https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/wen-public/Shared%20Documents
```

, and items in the document library

[image]

Create "Forms" folder in the document library will get HTTP 400 and Get "Forms" folder will get HTTP 404.

--

Tried to replace `drive` with `site` in endpoint

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/41fb0c3d-992c-4f9b-9b78-f5a390eea616,f8a65477-d88d-46d1-abeb-c4c34346e342/drive/root/children
HTTP 200 // responded 11 folders in the screenshot above
-
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/41fb0c3d-992c-4f9b-9b78-f5a390eea616,f8a65477-d88d-46d1-abeb-c4c34346e342/drive/root://:/children
HTTP 200 // responded 11 folders in the screenshot above
-
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/41fb0c3d-992c-4f9b-9b78-f5a390eea616,f8a65477-d88d-46d1-abeb-c4c34346e342/drive/root:/General:/children
HTTP 200
-
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/wen-public/drive/root/children
HTTP 400 
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Invalid hostname for this tenancy",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-05-30T09:43:13",
            "request-id": "37d3b218-2372-438b-8a35-eb31370db4d8",
            "client-request-id": "42e91019-d248-ae6f-0447-51411e57e792"
        }
    }
}
-
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/41fb0c3d-992c-4f9b-9b78-f5a390eea616,f8a65477-d88d-46d1-abeb-c4c34346e342/drive/root:/Forms:/children
HTTP 404
{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "The resource could not be found.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-05-30T09:46:00",
            "request-id": "1081e9eb-128d-47ce-a9ec-2295612e3a4e",
            "client-request-id": "bca1e92e-5361-5717-a1f0-457f2f7ddc07"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the directory structure？

Comment: @TinyWang I added a screenshot showing the directory structure

Comment: could you pls try `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/wen-public/drive/root:/Shared/Documents:/children`?

Comment: @TinyWang I tried and pasted the result. By the way, "Shared Document" is not a folder but a drive name.

Comment: I don't have any other ideas then...